# How prove this indentity$\langle F'',g\rangle=-\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x^{3/2}}dx$

Tags: functional-analysis

For the generalized function F defined as $\langle F,g\rangle =\int_{0}^{\infty}\sqrt{x}g(x)dx$,show  this the following equalities
$$\langle F'',g\rangle =-\dfrac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{g(x)-g(0)}{x^{3/2}}dx$$
where $g(\infty)=0,g'(\infty)=0$

I have some idea:
since 
$$\langle F'',g\rangle =\langle F,g''\rangle =\int_{0}^{\infty}\sqrt{x}dg'(x)=-\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{g'(x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx=-\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{dg(x)}{\sqrt{x}}$$
then I can't follow this indenitity

Comment: Please use `\langle,\rangle` to get $\langle,\rangle$. The relation symbols $<>$ not only look different, they produce different spacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** rewrite
$$
\langle F,g\rangle = \int_{\Bbb R} 1_{x>0} \sqrt{x} g(x) dx
$$
and **do not** forget the border terms.

---

the integral $$
-\int_{\Bbb R} 1_{x>0}  \frac{g'(x)}{2\sqrt{x}}  dx
$$
does not converge around $0$, but 
$$
-\int_{\Bbb R} 1_{x>0}  \frac{g'(x) - g'(0)}{2\sqrt{x}}  dx
$$does, when $g$ is smooth.

Then:
\begin{align}
\langle F'', g\rangle &= \langle F, g''\rangle
\\&= \int_0^\infty \sqrt x g''(x) dx
\\&= \left. \sqrt x (g'(x) - g'(0)) \right|_0^\infty 
- \int_0^\infty \frac{g'(x) - g'(0)}{2\sqrt x} dx
\\&= - \int_0^\infty \frac{g'(x) - g'(0)}{2\sqrt x} dx
\\&= \left. -\frac{g(x) - g(0) - x g'(0)}{2\sqrt x} \right|_0^\infty 
- \int_0^\infty \frac{g(x) - g(0) - x g'(0)}{4x^{3/2}}
\\
\end{align}$$
\langle F'', g\rangle = -\frac 14 \int_0^\infty \frac{g(x) - g(0) - x g'(0)}{x^{3/2}}
$$